# server 2003 to server 2008 R2 Foundation

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003

I'm wondering about the printers and file settings in GPME. This is a vanilla install (2008 R2 Foundation) that is replacing an older 2003 machine. I was thinking about starting a new domain and just joining all the computers/users to it. However, I would then need to go though and transfer all their profiles. And even if that went smoothly, there'd still be an issue with people's online banking not recognizing the computers....

What would be the easiest and most painless way to go about this? There aren't a whole ton of AD rules--could fairly easily re-write them. But I'm not sure about the other stuff; should I join the new server to the domain and then transfer, promote, then demote 2003? Should I just unplug the old and plug-in the new?

The main reason we are upgrading is faster disks.

We are using 2003 for:

- DNS
- AD
- Mail (local only)
- WINS
- Print (never worked correctly)
- Files

I'd love to take advantage of some of the things 2008 offers such as WDS for deploying new machines/re-imaging, but not critical. Also would like to get the print server working.

Thanks for any tips.

---

I forgot to mention that I *did* try to join the machine to the existing domain, but the process failed when 2008Foundation threw a licensing error (too many users).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add the new server as a DC to the existing domain. Then, also keep your old machine but upgrade the OS, because you should have 2 DCs per domain unless you're really on a shoestring budget and also wouldn't mind rebuilding your whole domain from scratch if you had a hardware failure.

Comment: Yeah, I forgot that I tried this; when I tried to join the existing domain 2008Foundation threw a license error (too many users). Very much shoestring budget--RAID and backups. Thanks...

Comment: @microchasm: Building a new domain isn't going to change the fact that you have to many users for the edition of Windows that you're going to roll out... unless you plan on purging (eliminating, firing) some users.

Comment: @joeqwerty thing is: I *don't* have too many users. It's just that fumbling around with 2003 for 5 years has led to quite a few stray accounts. I tried deleting the ones that I couldn't identify, but I think there are some created by programs or other ways (IIS installs/uninstalls etc.). I need this server to remain functional so I can't just go all willy-nilly deleting accounts. Thanks!

Comment: Try disabling the suspect ones for a week, make sure nothing fails and you're not getting weird errors in the event logs, and then delete them.

Comment: Also - get VMware player and evaluation ISOs for Windows Server so you can do your hands-on learning in a test environment, not on your only production server.

Comment: the licensing error you see on foundation server can be ignored.  i have a foundation server with 100 users and it works fine.  all you have to do is click OK on the error every time you log in do anything with user accounts.

Comment: @mfinni I did manage to get the 08 machine to join the domain. I tried again today, and it seems the few days that have passed cleared out the problem (I should have known to try the usual MSFT toolkit: do nothing and thing's will change inexplicably). I really can't afford to upgrade the 2003 machine; can I still use it as a DC? Does that eve make sense?

Comment: Yes, the 2003 DC can stay in the domain, you may be limited in what modes you can upgrade AD itself to. However, this probably won't affect you much. Word of advice : Learning AD can take a little while, but it's not difficult. Buy a book or take a course, because what you don't know can definitely hurt you. If you can self-study your way into an MCITP certification, you've done yourself a very good deed.

Comment: Thanks again. Now that the 08 machine is joined, I ran adprep et. al. and the 08 machine is now DC global catalog... IS there a way/should I demote 03? Or would I be better off leaving it? I can't even run dcpromo on 03 as cert svcs are running there which I assume I'd have to move. If this were your shop what would you do?

Comment: I would definitely have at least two DCs per domain, no matter what. As I said, if you don't have the budget to upgrade the OS on it, you can leave it at Win2k3. Also, to plan to retire a server absolutely involves having a complete migration plan for all of the services on it.